# Adding a class to a checkbox using .each Jquery

Tags: jquery

Looking to add a class to each span wrapping a checkbox, so I can change the background colour of each one when the checkbox is checked.

I have the js written. But cant seem to get the Jquery to affect each item.

Also is this the best way of creating this effect?

https://jsfiddle.net/L2m9b3wj/

JQUERY:

```
$('.product-select input').change(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $('.product-select .wpcf7-list-item').addClass("checkon");
            } else {
                $('.product-select .wpcf7-list-item').removeClass("checkon");
            }
        });
```

CSS:

```
.product-select {
    .wpcf7-list-item {
        width:30%;
        height:200px;
        background:red;
        display:inline-block;
        margin:0px auto;
    }

    .checkon {
        background:blue;
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="product-select">
     <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap checkbox-328"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first checkon"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-328[]" value="Flexible Benefits"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Flexible Benefits</span></span><span class="wpcf7-list-item checkon"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-328[]" value="Holiday &amp; Absence"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Holiday &amp; Absence</span></span><span class="wpcf7-list-item checkon"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-328[]" value="Employee Comms"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Employee Comms</span></span><span class="wpcf7-list-item last checkon"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-328[]" value="Custom Build"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Custom Build</span></span></span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(this).parents('span').addClass('checkon')`

Comment: Side note, don't do `$(this).is(":checked")`.  It's unnecessary when you already have the element.  Just use `this.checked` as it is a property on the Element.

Comment: Your CSS is written as either LESS or SCSS, which would need a compiler to turn it into CSS before the browser understands how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.product-select input').change(function() {  
  //get all the spans that are parents for the checkbox
  var $parentSpans = $(this).parents('span');

  if (this.checked) {
    $parentSpans.addClass('checkon');
  } else {
    $parentSpans.removeClass('checkon');
  }
});
```

```css
.product-select .wpcf7-list-item {
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.product-select .checkon {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-select">
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap checkbox-328"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first checkon"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-328[]" value="Flexible Benefits"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Flexible Benefits</span></span>
  <span class="wpcf7-list-item checkon"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-328[]" value="Holiday &amp; Absence"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Holiday &amp; Absence</span></span><span class="wpcf7-list-item checkon"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-328[]" value="Employee Comms"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Employee Comms</span></span>
  <span class="wpcf7-list-item last checkon"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-328[]" value="Custom Build"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Custom Build</span></span>
  </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.closest('span.wpcf7-list-item')` looks upwards the dom tree for the first parent matching the selector [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```js
$('.product-select input').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).closest('span.wpcf7-list-item').addClass("checkon");
  } else {
    $(this).closest('span.wpcf7-list-item').removeClass("checkon");
  }
});
```

```css
.product-select .wpcf7-list-item {
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.product-select .checkon {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-select">
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap checkbox-328"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first checkon"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-328[]" value="Flexible Benefits"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Flexible Benefits</span></span>
  <span
    class="wpcf7-list-item checkon"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-328[]" value="Holiday &amp; Absence"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Holiday &amp; Absence</span></span><span class="wpcf7-list-item checkon"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-328[]" value="Employee Comms"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Employee Comms</span></span>
    <span
      class="wpcf7-list-item last checkon"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-328[]" value="Custom Build"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Custom Build</span></span>
      </span>
      </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd do it this way

```
$('.product-select input').change(function(){
    $('.product-select input:checked').parent().removeClass('checkon').addClass('checkon');
    $('.product-select input').not(':checked').parent().removeClass('checkon');
});
```

I remove() and then add to avoid duplicates.